# Running Hadoop Job Through Web Interface

Tags: hadoop, web, vs-web-site-project

Is there any way to run Hadoop job through a web interface? e.g. giving command for Hadoop job execution with a button.
I want to implement a web interface for my Hadoop project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Cloudera will be useful, which is designed for this purpose.

http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/4.2.2/Hue-2-User-Guide/hue26.html

Comment: I have my own VMs. I guess this tutorial will not work for that. Or will it?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below options :

**Option -1**

1. Create a java web project with Web service and Add all UI inputs to this client server.
2. Create another web project as remote server , And receive all the above inputs of the job and pass it to the Jobs.

The remote server web project should be in the cluster always up and running, and capturing the client signals.

Use JSCH in the server side and invoke as and when all the hadoop commands you pass from the UI.

OR

**Option - 2**

You could you a MySql database and store all job parameters from the UI . Then write a simple java code with JSCH to run these hadoop comands by polling the DB. A runnable jar running all time.

Hope the above 2 ideas help you.